# Master Table Information required for the Replication Process

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005 while doing Replication (Snap Shot/ Transactional/ Marge Replication), what are the master tables are used ?

Answer (score 2):

The Master table is used in snapshot replication and contains metadata about the replication, the current state of the snapshot, and rollback information in the event a transaction fails. Normally you can just forget about it, but in certain cases you can (very carefully) modify it directly, and save a lot of time instead of regenerating the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Replication in SQL Server 2005 is managed with reference to a group of system tables in the MSDB database, along with one in Master, and some tables in the Distribution, Publication and Subscription databases.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179855(SQL.90).aspx :

> A replication topology is supported by replication system tables. When 
>   a user database is configured as a Publisher or a Subscriber, 
>   replication adds system tables to the database. These tables are 
>   removed when a user database is removed from a replication topology.